# What was Eitri making along with Stormbreaker?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

During a watch of Infinity War, I noticed that during the scene where they make Stormbreaker there was a **second mold** being filled but it wasn't for Stormbreaker since it **[looks like both parts of Stormbreaker come from the same mold.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fhc2lCoMgIY&feature=youtu.be&t=65)**

**Eitri was making something else along with Stormbreaker, What is that?**

[image]

Didn't get satisfied answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieDetails/comments/976iwr/infinity_war_eitri_was_making_something_else/e45uyod/)

Comment: Did you ask __[this question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieDetails/comments/976iwr/infinity_war_eitri_was_making_something_else/e45uyod/)__ 2 months ago, or did you just copy & paste it (including the picture) without giving credit?

Comment: Adding a link at the end doesn't really fix the problem, since it still reads like you are the one who noticed this and made the screenshot, even though it was someone else. You shouldn't take someone elses work and pretend it's your own.

Comment: Yes, I did noticed and I searched for the problem and I also captured the screen shots But then I find this one so I put it, So what is the problem ?

Comment: @AdityaShah Hi! It looks like you just copied most of this content from the link pointed out by Oliver. Can you edit your post and give attribution to the author? Plagiarism isn't really welcomed on Stack Exchange and it's always [nice to give credit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where credit is due. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

**Handle?**

Because that's what Etiri was not able to find later:

> He needs the axe!
>   Where's the handle?
>   Tree, help me find the handle!

Comment: I upvoted, but it's pretty weird he couldn't find it...

Comment: @GordonBennett they were in hurry, universe was on stake

Comment: It just can't be a handle 'cause the second mold is the same as the first.

Comment: @VerNick we never see second mold upclose

Comment: @AnkitSharma But we see how melted iron spreads.

Comment: @VerNick but we never break the mold to see inside shape

Comment: @AnkitSharma I think Eitri wasn't so stupid not to find the handle which was a few steps from axe.

Comment: @VerNick so you mean to say Eitri lied and he tricked Groot?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I mean it can't be handle, because Eitri would use it.

Comment: @VerNick then where was handle?

Comment: @AnkitSharma https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/26/avengers-directors-groot-stormbreaker-theory/ here you are, it explains all.

Comment: @VerNick that's speculation about new handle , I am talking about how come they lost old handle and which mold they used to make it if not the right one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85964/discussion-between-ver-nick-and-ankit-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

I think that dwarfs before Thanos killed them used a sophisticated system of mass production so they were doing many copies of a one detail at the same time. Eitri had no time(and hands) for fixing this mass production. So I think that the second mold is the same as for Thor's axe. We can even see that it is absolutely the same as 
the first on the photo.
 Also, Eitri didn't use that mold, what means he don't need this detail.

---

I don't change my mind but here is what directors answered to a related question **[here](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/26/avengers-directors-groot-stormbreaker-theory/)**:

> As for Stormbreaker, Groot was alongside Rocket and Thor during
>   Stormbreaker's creation. While the blade for Stormbreaker was
>   finished, the mold fell over before the handle could be created, and
>   to save Thor Groot uses his limbs to form the handle and unite the
>   weapon, saving Thor in the process.